# Checking checkboxes with webbrowser element

Tags: c#, button, checkbox, browser

Today i tried to write a program which checks some checkboxes for me on a webpage and then clicks on a button.

For this purpose i tried to use the webbrowser, but how can I set the state of a checkbox there? Searching the internet for hours but no luck only managed to navigate to the webpage with the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to write a [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), where you create a bookmark that runs JavaScript code, and the other would be to avoid the web browser altogether and instead just send a request directly to the web server that looks like it would if you had checked the checkboxes and clicked the button.  Using a tool like wget or curl can make the latter option pretty easy.

Here's a sample URL that you could use to go for the Bookmarklet approach:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('theCheckBox').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
```

The easiest way to do the second approach would be to use a tool like Firebug or Fiddler to monitor what a request looks like when you manually submit a page with your checkboxes checked and then construct similar requests through curl.

Comment: many thanks. got it now, just sniffed the post request with livehttpheaders in firefox and made the same post with my webbrowser.
EDIT: But the Webbrowser always opens a new window when navigating ):
how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Using a WebBrowser control is not really a good approach here. The purpose of this control is to *display* a webpage, not to automate user interaction with it.

The most easy and most reliable solution is to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to directly talk to the server, sending a (most likely) POST request.

Comment: is it also possible with httpwebrequest to store cookies, check checkboxes and buttons on sites?